# Inbound APIM Policy Adds 'Body' Parent Property to Original Request

Tags: rest, azure-api-management, splunk, azure-eventhub

I have created an API that will be used to send log messages to Azure EventHub that will then be consumed by Splunk. In APIM there an inbound policy that will add/remove properties from the incoming request as necessary. The 'Set-Body' portion of the policy looks like this:

```
<set-body>@{
   var requestBody = context.Request.Body.As&lt;JObject&gt;(preserveContent: true);

   if (requestBody["Timestamp"] == null)
   {
      requestBody["Timestamp"] = DateTime.UtcNow;
   }

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)requestBody["StackTrace"]))
   {
      requestBody.Remove("StackTrace");
   }

   var eventObject = new JObject();
   eventObject["event"] = requestBody;

   return eventObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
}</set-body>
```

The incoming request body is as follows:

```
{
  "Source": "postman-test",
  "Environment": "Local",
  "Severity": "Error",
  "Message": "An error occurred.",
  "Timestamp": "2022-04-30T14:30:01Z",
  "Host": "localhost",
  "StackTrace": "at FunctionApp.ABC.ServiceAgent.XYZ.SendRequest(Foo request) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\FunctionApp.ABC\\ServiceAgent\\XYZ.cs:line 26",
  "AdditionalProperties": {
    "Id": 123,
    "ExecutionDuration": 400.8,
    "InnerExceptionMessage": "Network error"
  }
}
```

However, it appears that this policy is adding a 'Body' property to the original request body. This is what the json looks like once it makes it's way to splunk (the missing '}' at the end is intentional as this is how it appears in Splunk):

```
{
  "body":{
    "event":{
      "Source":"postman-test",
      "Environment":"Local",
      "Severity":"Error",
      "Message":"An error occurred.",
      "Timestamp":"2022-04-30T14:30:01Z",
      "Host":"localhost",
      "StackTrace":"at FunctionApp.ABC.ServiceAgent.XYZ.SendRequest(Foo request) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\FunctionApp.ABC\\ServiceAgent\\XYZ.cs:line 26",
      "AdditionalProperties":{
        "Id":123,
        "ExecutionDuration":400.8,
        "InnerExceptionMessage":"Network error"
      }
    }
  }
```

This is the desired output from APIM:

```
{
  "event": {
    "Source": "postman-test",
    "Environment": "Local",
    "Severity": "Error",
    "Message": "An error occurred.",
    "Timestamp": "2022-04-30T14:30:01Z",
    "Host": "localhost",
    "StackTrace": "at FunctionApp.ABC.ServiceAgent.XYZ.SendRequest(Foo request) in D:\\a\\1\\s\\FunctionApp.ABC\\ServiceAgent\\XYZ.cs:line 26",
    "AdditionalProperties": {
      "Id": 123,
      "ExecutionDuration": 400.8,
      "InnerExceptionMessage": "Network error"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what does your sourcetype's props.conf and transforms.conf look like? How are you ingesting this data?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing source with event in the Regex

```
<when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode == 200)">
<set-body>@{
var response = context.Response.Body.As<JArray>();
var sty = Regex.Replace(response.ToString(),@"\bId\b","EmployeeId");
return sty.ToString();
```